# Appending list with class-object overwrites all previous list elements

Tags: python, list, append

I spent quite some time trying to figure out what the problem is and already tried several ways that I found in other questions but still it does not work. I want to store all my class objects in the list "houselist" but instead of appending the list it just gives me several time the same entry. I guess it's some kind of reference issue but I can't figure it out. Here's the code:

```
# Definition of the house object class
class House_object():
    def __init__(self, price, surfaceArea, rent, tNumber, adress, monthlyCost, areaCost):
        self.price = price
        self.surfaceArea = surfaceArea
        self.rent = rent
        self.tNumber = tNumber
        self.adress = adress
        self.monthlyCost = monthlyCost
        self.areaCost = areaCost

#reading the file
f = open("bfil.txt", "r")
content = f.read()
splitlist = content.split("\n")
f.close()

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('bfil.txt'))

#creating the list "houselist" and adding the class instances to it
houselist = []
for i in range(0, num_lines, 5):
    price = int(splitlist[0 + i])
    surfaceArea = int(splitlist[1 + i])
    rent = int(splitlist[2 + i])
    tNumber = splitlist[3 + i]
    adress = splitlist[4 + i]
    monthlyCost = int(rent + (((price - dPayment) * (bankRate / 100) * (1 - (intrestDeduct / 100))) / 12))
    areaCost = int(price / rent)
    bostad = House_object(price, surfaceArea, rent, tNumber, adress, monthlyCost, areaCost)

    houselist.append(bostad) # I think here might be the problem??

    for element in houselist:
        print("this is the list during the loop: " + bostad.adress)
```

The print command at the end gives me the following:

```
this is the list during the loop: Streetgatan 1
this is the list during the loop: KTHstreet 7
this is the list during the loop: KTHstreet 7
this is the list during the loop: weststreet 66
this is the list during the loop: weststreet 66
this is the list during the loop: weststreet 66
this is the list during the loop: Delilstreet 57
this is the list during the loop: Delilstreet 57
this is the list during the loop: Delilstreet 57
this is the list during the loop: Delilstreet 57
```

So with every loop, python overwrites my list and adds the new instance but replaces also the already existing ones.
I would have expected this:

```
this is the list during the loop: Streetgatan 1
this is the list during the loop: Streetgatan 1
this is the list during the loop: KTHstreet 7
this is the list during the loop: Streetgatan 1
this is the list during the loop: KTHstreet 7
this is the list during the loop: weststreet 66
this is the list during the loop: Streetgatan 1
this is the list during the loop: KTHstreet 7
this is the list during the loop: weststreet 66
this is the list during the loop: Delilstreet 57
```

I tried both
    houselist.append(bostad) 
and 
    houselist = houselist[:] + bostad

I read in some other posts about this possibility, so I tried this, but still gives me the same result. I am very thankful for any help!

Comment: You are printing inside your main loop. Move the print statement out of first for loop

Comment: I think OP is very aware of that, since 1) does he print "this is the list **during** the loop" and 2) does his desired output match the print being **inside** of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are not printing the right thing:

```
houselist.append(bostad) # I think here might be the problem??

for element in houselist:
    print("this is the list during the loop: " + bostad.adress)
```

you are printing `bostad.adress`, so you are just printing the adress of the last appended item instead of:

```
for element in houselist:
    print("this is the list during the loop: " + element.adress)
```

Comment: Wow, once you told me, it seems so obvious! Thanks a lot!!